# Python Easy Way to Match String Input to existing dictionary

Tags: python, string, batch-file, dictionary

I'm writing a test that will run on multiple forms.  I have created a batch file that will send in an argument containing the form name (so technically the test only runs once per batch file).  I have a dictionary for each test in which I want to match to the input of the argument.  So let's say I have:

```
import sys

form1 = {
  a = 3,
  b = 4
}
form2 = {
  a = 7,
  b = 8
}

args = sys.argv[1] #this would be the form input as a string; example: "form1"
```

I would like a way to have it know that "form1" matches with the dictionary form1.  Obviously, I could do something like:

```
if args == "form1":
  form = form1
elif args == "form2":
  form = form2
...
```

However, with 27 tests, I'd rather not have to deal with that.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Something along the lines of:

```
form = matchvar(args)
runtest(form)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary with your encompassing forms, then lookup the key with the value you get from the command line:

```
forms = dict()
forms['form1'] = {a:3, b:4}
forms['form2'] = {a:7, b:8}

form = forms.get(args)
if form:
   runtest(form)
else:
   print('Invalid form: {}'.format(args))
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this one to work, and the command line closes before telling me anything.  what is the forms.get(args) supposed to do?  I haven't actually used get() before, but what I'm seeing is that you would need 2 arguments in it?

Comment: or is it the same as saying form = forms[args]? (only yours will raise an error if it's not there)

Comment: @user2869231 The second argument is optional, and specifies what to return if the key isn't found.

Comment: so I changed the a=3, b=4 to a:3, b:4 because it was expecting a colon; however, now it is telling me that name 'a' is not defined - that is how I've always written dictionaries o.O

Comment: ah, just needed to put them in quotes - it was reading them as a variable

Answer (score 2):

Dare I suggest a dictionary of dictionaries?

```
formdict = { "form1": form1, "form2": form2 }
```

Then you can access the right dictionary with `formdict.get(args,[])`.

```
>>> formdict["form1"]["a"]
3
>>> formdict["form2"]["a"]
7
```

Comment: you can give formdict.get(args,[]) since if no args it give error

Comment: hmm... something about this, though, is each dictionary is rather large.  I have the dictionaries called quite frequently, so I'd have to go back and change them all

Comment: given that I could technically just set each key to the currently used variables....

Comment: Well you could assign them more easily using Burhan Khalid's solution, yea. I wasn't sure how much the dictionaries would be changing.